# Drag Over UIButton to Activate

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uigesturerecognizer

I'm working on an app where the user long presses which pulls up a radial menu, and then while they continue to press they drag either up, down left or right to select a button.

I want to change the state of the button when the user drags their figure into that button, but the issue I'm running into is that the main view is the view that registers the longPress, but then I need the subView to register the touches.

I've tried gestures and touches without much success. I think I may need to implement a delegate class somehow, but not sure where to begin.

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code to use for multiple gestures

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTapWebView:)];
doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTap.delegate = self;
[self.webViewParent addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
[doubleTap release];

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapWebView:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
singleTap.delegate = self;
[self.webViewParent addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
[singleTap release];
```

Here I have resolved the conflict created when using multiple gestures. You may use :

```
 [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
```

if you want to use multiple conflicting gestures.